# Ricoh Aficio prints text instead of the CUPS print test page

Tags: printing

I'm trying to print to a Ricoh Aficio printer, my OS is Ubuntu 11.10 on a Sony laptop.

When I connect it it all seems ok, in the sense the printer appears on the printer list and is recognised as the correct model.

However when I send a test page the folllowing occurs.

Instead of printing a test page it prints the following text:

"CUPS PrintTestPage"

not sure why this is happening... Any help would be much appreciated.

best

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.